# Cant change a button state to 'DISABLED' in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-scale

I am using a theme in tkinter and it's not allowing me to change state of scale (to control volume of a music player).Before applying the theme it was working fine so i am assuming it's because of the theme.

code :

```
vol_control = ttk.Scale(l_frame, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL,command=set_vol)
vol_control.set(35)
vol_control.pack(side = LEFT ,padx=15)


vol_control.config(state=DISABLED)
```

it returns this error when i try to change volume :

```
in _configure
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"
```

Comment: Change to `vol_control.state(['disabled'])`

Comment: To clear the disabled flag, use `vol_control.state(['!disabled'])`. Read about [The full list of state flags available to themed widgets](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#button)